# How do I save a 2d list after editing it in this bit of code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

*Edit: fixed recursion with loop. I still don't understand how to pass the new grocery data after add_product function to main*

*Edit: added the main function definition that I missed somehow in initial copy/paste*

I'm writing a program that will create an editable database for a fictional business.  The initial database is a 2d list of 6 lists, with 4 items within each of those 6 lists.

My program starts by welcoming the user, then displaying a set of commands based on user input of 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4.

Options 1-4 each call a separate function, option 0 exits the program.  After the function in option 1-4 is called, the program restarts by displaying the set of commands

I'm having trouble restarting at the display of commands combined with storing the results of the edited initial 2d list after creating a new list and using .append to add it on to the end of my initial list.  My program will restart where I want it to after running the add_product function, but the new list is only saved within the definition of my add_product function, whereas I would like it to be saved in my main function definition.

I feel like I may have a misplaced assignment statement, or something out of order.  I feel like I'm very close, and any hits or suggestions would be appreciated.

I've only been coding for 4 weeks so please ignore other errors at the present time.

First post, sorry for terrible syntax and not following the rules

```py
def main ():
    grocery_data = [["Milk", 95520, 3.27, 20], ["Eggs", 55504, 2.97, 15], ["Bread", 57971, 2.78, 20], ["Apples", 19791, 0.78, 70], ["Cheese Bits", 32510, 2.99, 25], ["Cheese Bytes", 84519, 23.92, 10]]
    print("Welcome to Guido's Groceries Item Database")
    print("")
    user_input()
def user_input ():
    print("")
    print("Enter 1 to display the table of our products")
    print("Enter 2 to add a product")
    print("Enter 3 to caclulate the average cost of the items")
    print("Enter 4 to caclulate the total number of individual items")
    print("Enter 0 to exit the program")
    print("")
    option = int(input("What would you like to do? "))
    print("")
    grocery_data = [["Milk", 95520, 3.27, 20], ["Eggs", 55504, 2.97, 15], ["Bread", 57971, 2.78, 20], ["Apples", 19791, 0.78, 70], ["Cheese Bits", 32510, 2.99, 25], ["Cheese Bytes", 84519, 23.92, 10]]

    if option == 1:
        display_table(grocery_data)
    elif option == 2:
        grocery_data.append(add_product(grocery_data))        
    elif option == 3:
        avg_price(grocery_data)
    elif option == 4:
        total_stock(grocery_data)
    elif option == 0:
        exit_program()
    else:
        exit_program()


def display_table(grocery_data): 
    print("Product Name".ljust(15), "UPC".ljust(15), "Price".ljust(15), "Number in Stock".ljust(15), sep="")
    for row in grocery_data:
        print("{: <14} {: <14} {: <14} {: <14}".format(*row))
    print("")
    user_input()

def add_product(grocery_data):
    grocery_data.append([str(input("Please enter the product name: ")), int(input("Please enter the UPC: ")), float(input("Please enter the price: ")), int(input("Please enter the number in stock: "))])
    print(grocery_data)    
    user_input()

main()
```

second try

```py
def main ():
    grocery_data = [["Milk", 95520, 3.27, 20], ["Eggs", 55504, 2.97, 15], ["Bread", 57971, 2.78, 20], ["Apples", 19791, 0.78, 70], ["Cheese Bits", 32510, 2.99, 25], ["Cheese Bytes", 84519, 23.92, 10]]
    print("Welcome to Guido's Groceries Item Database")
    print("")
    user_input()

def user_input ():

    while True:

        print("")
        print("Enter 1 to display the table of our products")
        print("Enter 2 to add a product")
        print("Enter 3 to caclulate the average cost of the items")
        print("Enter 4 to caclulate the total number of individual items")
        print("Enter 0 to exit the program")
        print("")
        option = int(input("What would you like to do? "))
        print("")
        grocery_data = [["Milk", 95520, 3.27, 20], ["Eggs", 55504, 2.97, 15], ["Bread", 57971, 2.78, 20], ["Apples", 19791, 0.78, 70], ["Cheese Bits", 32510, 2.99, 25], ["Cheese Bytes", 84519, 23.92, 10]]



        if option == 1:
            display_table(grocery_data)
        if option == 2:
            add_product(grocery_data)


        if option == 3:
            avg_price(grocery_data)
        if option == 4:
            total_stock(grocery_data)
        if option == 0:
            break


def display_table(grocery_data): 
    print("Product Name".ljust(15), "UPC".ljust(15), "Price".ljust(15), "Number in Stock".ljust(15), sep="")
    for row in grocery_data:
        print("{: <14} {: <14} {: <14} {: <14}".format(*row))
    print("")
    return

def add_product(grocery_data):
    new_item = []
    new_item.append([str(input("Please enter the product name: ")), int(input("Please enter the UPC: ")), float(input("Please enter the price: ")), int(input("Please enter the number in stock: "))])
    grocery_data.append(new_item)
    print(grocery_data)
    return

main()
```

Comment: User_Input is declaring a new grocery_data set everything it is called, is that purposeful?

Comment: Where should I prompt the user for more input after the call to add_product then? That is the purpose of the call to user_input after the action function, the program is supposed to reprompt the user for a new choice after performing any action except exit

Comment: ah like a for loop? I think I see where you're going with this

Comment: @TomKarzes Can you check out my loop edit? Evan VanderZee below fixed my modified grocery_data variable passing, but I'd like to get it working with the loop as you suggested.  Thank you

Comment: @MicahHogan Much better!  Also note that the bare returns at the end of your dispatch functions can be removed since they don't really do anything.  You would only need them if they were returning a value, or if they weren't at the end of the functoin.

Comment: @TomKarzes I'm still stuck on the original question after the simplification though: What am I doing incorrectly to have the modified grocery_data list passed back to main and stored there?

Comment: Nevermind, I think I got it.  Thanks for all the thoughtful input

Comment: @MicahHogan You need to change `user_input` so that it's like the dispatch functions:  Pass `grocery_data` as an argument to it, and remove the duplicate initialization of it from `user_input`.

Comment: @TomKarzes yep, got it, thanks again. posted my answer below

Answer (score 0):

The main reason that your example program is not behaving as you expect is that you redefine `grocery_data` every time that the `user_input` function is called.  Although it would be a better solution to use some type of looping structure, as Tom Karzes is suggesting in the comments, here is a version of your program that passes `grocery_data` into the `user_input` method.  In this case, the `add_product` method makes its modified `grocery_data` visible to the `user_input` method by passing it when it recursively calls `user_input`.

```
def main ():
    grocery_data = [["Milk", 95520, 3.27, 20], ["Eggs", 55504, 2.97, 15], ["Bread", 57971, 2.78, 20], ["Apples", 19791, 0.78, 70], ["Cheese Bits", 32510, 2.99, 25], ["Cheese Bytes", 84519, 23.92, 10]]
    print("Welcome to Guido's Groceries Item Database")
    print("")
    user_input(grocery_data)

def user_input(grocery_data):
    print("")
    print("Enter 1 to display the table of our products")
    print("Enter 2 to add a product")
    print("Enter 3 to caclulate the average cost of the items")
    print("Enter 4 to caclulate the total number of individual items")
    print("Enter 0 to exit the program")
    print("")
    option = int(input("What would you like to do? "))
    print("")

    if option == 1:
        display_table(grocery_data)
    elif option == 2:
        add_product(grocery_data)

def display_table(grocery_data): 
    print("Product Name".ljust(15), "UPC".ljust(15), "Price".ljust(15), "Number in Stock".ljust(15), sep="")
    for row in grocery_data:
        print("{: <14} {: <14} {: <14} {: <14}".format(*row))
    print("")
    user_input(grocery_data)

def add_product(grocery_data):
    grocery_data.append([str(input("Please enter the product name: ")), int(input("Please enter the UPC: ")), float(input("Please enter the price: ")), int(input("Please enter the number in stock: "))])
    user_input(grocery_data)

main()
```

This still isn't a good way to implement a solution because it uses recursion unnecessarily, but I have partially answered the question of why the modified `grocery_data` is not visible in the `user_input` method.

I should also note that both in your original program and in this version, the modification that is made to `grocery_data` is visible in the `user_input` method if/when program control is returned to the `user_input` method that invoked the `add_product` method.  To verify that, you can drop the call to `user_input` that is in the `add_product` method and add a statement at the end of `user_input` that prints out `grocery_data`.  The program will terminate at that point because there is no looping structure that would return execution back to near the top of the `user_input` method, but you would see that the list is being modified correctly inside of `add_product` in a way that does make it visible to `user_input`.

Comment: I fixed the recursion and went with looping because I understand that it is simpler.

Comment: Could you look at the edited code with fixed recursion and suggest how to pass the modified grocery_data back into user_input?  Sorry for the stupid questions

Comment: nevermind, I think I got it.  Thanks for all the thoughtful input.

Answer (score 0):

This code does what my original question asked, in addition to clearing up the unnecessary recursions

```py
def main ():
    grocery_data = [["Milk", 95520, 3.27, 20], ["Eggs", 55504, 2.97, 15], ["Bread", 57971, 2.78, 20], ["Apples", 19791, 0.78, 70], ["Cheese Bits", 32510, 2.99, 25], ["Cheese Bytes", 84519, 23.92, 10]]
    print("Welcome to Guido's Groceries Item Database")
    print("")
    user_input(grocery_data)

def user_input (grocery_data):

    while True:

        print("")
        print("Enter 1 to display the table of our products")
        print("Enter 2 to add a product")
        print("Enter 3 to caclulate the average cost of the items")
        print("Enter 4 to caclulate the total number of individual items")
        print("Enter 0 to exit the program")
        print("")
        option = int(input("What would you like to do? "))
        print("")

        if option == 1:
            display_table(grocery_data)
        if option == 2:
            add_product(grocery_data)


        if option == 3:
            avg_price(grocery_data)
        if option == 4:
            total_stock(grocery_data)
        if option == 0:
            break


def display_table(grocery_data): 
    print("Product Name".ljust(15), "UPC".ljust(15), "Price".ljust(15), "Number in Stock".ljust(15), sep="")
    for row in grocery_data:
        print("{: <14} {: <14} {: <14} {: <14}".format(*row))
    print("")

def add_product(grocery_data):
    product_name = str(input("Please enter the product name: "))
    grocery_data.append([product_name, int(input("Please enter the UPC: ")), float(input("Please enter the price: ")), int(input("Please enter the number in stock: "))])

    print(product_name + " has been added!")

main()
```